# Knockoutjs: data-binding an 'href' attribute results in a link which does nothing when clicked

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockoutjs to dynamically render an anchor tag on a template.

My HTML template looks like this:

```
<!-- ko if: [observable condition] -->
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: ChangeLogUrl }">View change log</a>
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When the view is initially rendered the condition is not met so the anchor tag isn't displayed.

When the condition *is* met the anchor tag is then rendered. I can inspect the page's HTML and everything is as expected and the `href` attribute is formed correctly. Hovering over the link reveals the URL in the bottom-left of the browser window.

However, clicking the link has no effect.

I can add a `title` attribute in that same `attr: {...}` binding and this *will* be displayed; I can even add an `onclick` attribute like this:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { onclick: 'javascript:alert(\'hello world\');' }">
```

and this also functions as expected when I click on the anchor tag.

Furthermore, the HTML template is also used in another view using the same view-model, but in this case the condition *is* met when the view is initially rendered, and in this situation the anchor tag *is* clickable.

So why is it that the `href` attribute has no effect when it is dynamically rendered?

Comment: depends what you're putting in there bro. sounds like you're not putting anything.

Comment: any error you get in console when you click it?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis LIke I said in the post, " I can inspect the page's HTML and everything is as expected and the href attribute is formed correctly. Hovering over the link reveals the URL in the bottom-left of the browser window." In other words, the `href` attribute *is* being populated exactly as I want it to be.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other handlers on your page that could be interfering?  [It should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/okwLbwh7/2/)

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion Nope, no errors during data-binding *or* when I click on the link.

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's a good question and it's an idea which has already had me poring over the template and other templates which wrap it... but I can't find anything. And like I said, I'm using the very same template, built on the same view-model, on another page and it works fine. The only difference is that the condition is 'pre-met'.

Comment: any possiblity for jsfiddle?

Comment: I just put together a jsfiddle demo but it works there. The only difference I can offer between that and mine is that the jsfiddle has a single template and a single view-model, whereas both of mine are nested several levels.

Comment: In the end the whole Knockout/viewmodel construct is ephemeral. All that counts is the value of the `href` property of the DOM object when you click on the link. So the other logical thing to investigate is whether the click event *actually reaches* the DOM event or is canceled before that.

Comment: Yes, very true. In my OP I mentioned that I'd added an `onclick` attribute and that this *does* something when I click it. Wouldn't that imply that the click event isn't being cancelled too early?

Comment: Unfortunately it's on a customer-only website, and I don't fancy the idea of putting test user login details here.

Comment: It sounds like something is either intercepting the a onclick event, potentially from a different scope (look for event handlers that return false/event.preventDefault) OR something is intercepting your history/pushState. Unfortunately, as you can't reproduce this in a fiddle, the problem is not here.

Comment: Yes, I'm inclined to agree, which is what @JamesThorpe suggested earlier. Unfortunately in the time that all these comments have been coming in, I've still been trying to find out what else might be interfering with it, and have come up empty-handed.

Comment: Groan - a downvote without explanation.

Comment: Counter-acted... (and my answer deleted, a completely unanswered question attracts more attention)